# Look at this rhombus problem

Tags: geometry

ABCD is a rhombus. A stright line through C cuts AD produced at P and AB produced at Q. If 2DP=AB then ratio of lengths of BQ and AB ?

What i did is i"i take tringle APQ and triangle ABD and make them similar because angle A is common in both triangles and Angle ADB = angle APQ and Angle ABD = angle AQP. and then AD/DP = AB/BQ. by this way i got BQ:AB = 1:2."

But the answer is 2:1. Please tell where i am wrong in my solution

Comment: how can a line though C cut both AD and AB?

Comment: no sir it meets Ad and AB

Answer (score 1):

$APQ$ and $ABD$ are not similar. That's where you are making a mistake. There is no way you can prove that $\angle ADB = \angle APQ$. What is true is that $\angle ADB \neq \angle APQ$.

The proof goes like this:

Since $ABCD$ is a rhombus, $AB = AD$ and thus the relation $2 DP = AB$ becomes
$$\frac{DP}{AB} = \frac{DP}{AD} = \frac{1}{2} = \frac{CP}{QC}$$ because $DC$ is parallel to $AB$ and thus to $AQ$. Here you can prove that triangles $PDC$ and $PAQ$ are similar, but it is simpler to just reference the intercept theorem (Thales' theorem).

Finally, again by the fact that $ABCD$ is a rhombus, $BC$ is parallel to $AD$ and thus to $AP$, so again by the intercept theorem 
$$\frac{1}{2} = \frac{CP}{QC} = \frac{AB}{BQ}$$  or if you prefer $BQ : AB = 2:1$ and not the other way around!